# toggle menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am trying a toggle menu for my website. But it is not working. I want that when anyone clicks on the link,a menu opens there instead of a new page. Following is a html and 
java script snippet.

```
<div>
 <a href="http://directory/websites.jsp" class="menu_link">Menu</a>
 <ul class="menu" id="websites">
    <li><i>Stackexchange</i> <br/>
     <a href="#">SE</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

*js :*

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
   var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   for( var i=0 ; i<allLinks.length ; i++ ) {
      if(allLinks[i].className.indexOf("menu_link") > -1) {
          allLinks[i].onclick = toggleMenu;
      }
   }
}

function toggleMenu() {
  var start = this.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
  var stop = this.href.lastIndexOf(".");
  var thisMenuName = this.href.substring(start,stop);
  var thisMenu = document.getElementById(thisMenuName).style;

  if(thisMenu.display == "block") {
     thisMenu.display = "none";
  } else {
     thisMenu.display = "block";
  }

  return false;    
}
```

Where am I making the mistake ?

Comment: your html is not complete. where is UL which contain your hide option

Comment: put thisMenu.style.display instead of thisMenu.display

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
 <a href="http://directory/websites.jsp" class="menu_link">
 <ul class="menu" id="websites">
    <li><i>Stackexchange</i> <br/>
     <a href="#" class="menu_link">SE</a>
<ul id="menu">
<li>abc...</li>
<li>abc...</li>
</ul>

    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your function work on class name "menu_link" which you mention in your function. allLinks[i].className.indexOf("menu_link")

Comment: Then? What mistake have I made?  Please make that clear. And include this in your answer

Comment: I have included menu_link class on a tag. you did not mention menu_link class on a tag

Comment: will you please reread the code what I want to do ? SE is an entry in the menu.